# Curl or read each line of url text file, then output each to separate files labelled as consecutive numbers- 1 2 3 etc

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, sh

I have a text file, which contains a list of 32 url's- i'll call it url.txt

I would like to curl the output of each url, and for each result/output, produce a separate file (so there would be a separate file for each url). I would like each consecutive file produced to be labelled with a number, starting from 1 up to 32. The number of url's might increase in the future so if the code could someone name each url from 1 to whatever the number of last url in the list, that would be even better. What is the simplest way of me achieving this?

EDIT- additional info example of urls (they are api searches):

```
http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems&SERVICE-NAME=FindingService&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=myappname-DATA-FORMAT=XML&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&REST-PAYLOAD&itemFilter(0).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(0).value=true&itemFilter(1).name=Condition&itemFilter(1).value=3000&itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue=GBP&itemFilter(2).value=55&itemFilter(3).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(3).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(3).paramValue=GBP&itemFilter(3).value=300&categoryId=11233&locatedIn=European&keywords=vinyl+-collection+-signed+-single+-singles&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1&paginationInput.pageNumber=1

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems&SERVICE-NAME=FindingService&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=myappname-DATA-FORMAT=XML&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&REST-PAYLOAD&itemFilter(0).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(0).value=true&itemFilter(1).name=Condition&itemFilter(1).value=3000&itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue=GBP&itemFilter(2).value=55&itemFilter(3).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(3).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(3).paramValue=GBP&itemFilter(3).value=300&categoryId=11233&locatedIn=European&keywords=vinyl+-collection+-signed+-single+-singles&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1&paginationInput.pageNumber=2
```

Comment: Are the URLs related in any way? Do they have the numbers you want in them? Do you need the output to contain numbers or could they contain part of (or the entirety) of the URLs being fetched? Does the `#1`, etc. support of the `curl` `-o` option help at all?

Comment: HI, yes i've updated my query with an example, the url's are related, they  are subsequent pages of an api url search and each page end in 1  2  3  etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` supports downloading ranges of pages and supports outputting those pages into numbered (or other) unique filenames.

For your URLs try:

```
curl -o 'output_#1.file' 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findCompletedItems&SERVICE-NAME=FindingService&SERVICE-VERSION=1.13.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=myappname-DATA-FORMAT=XML&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&REST-PAYLOAD&itemFilter(0).name=SoldItemsOnly&itemFilter(0).value=true&itemFilter(1).name=Condition&itemFilter(1).value=3000&itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue=GBP&itemFilter(2).value=55&itemFilter(3).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(3).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(3).paramValue=GBP&itemFilter(3).value=300&categoryId=11233&locatedIn=European&keywords=vinyl+-collection+-signed+-single+-singles&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1&paginationInput.pageNumber=[1-32]'
```

Answer (score 0):

for example you can do it this way:

```
cat url.txt | perl -e '$c=1;while(<>){chomp;`curl $_ > $c 2>/dev/null`;$c++}'
```

Answer (score 0):

in pure bash, you can do:

```
C=0; while read p; do C=$(($C+1)); curl "$p" > "$C.out"; done < url.txt
```